# Wait for callback to be returned in a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I want to upload some files, add them to a database and return the ids of the new objects.

```
fn: async function (inputs) {

  let docIds = []
  let settings = {...}

  await inputs.filesToUpload.upload(settings, async (err, files) => {

    if (err)
        throw {'invalid': 'The provided data is invalid.'}

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
        let newDocument = await Document.create({
          name: file.filename
        }).fetch()
        docIds.push(newDocument.id)
    }

  })

  return {
    ids: docIds
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, the controller doesn't wait for the objects to be created in the database and returns {ids: []} immediately, only then the documents are uploaded and objects created. I have tried using passing the ids as a callback and promise but the controller always executes return without waiting for the results.

Comment: I could give an answer here, but this old post gives a WAY better explanation/solution than I could give, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766002/9040866

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inputs.filesToUpload.upload` is making a callback which is always going to be asynchronous.

async keyword before a function with callback can not make it wait.

async works only if the function is returning a promise

check following code where I have extracted the upload flow in a separate function that returns a promise

you can then await on this promise and get generated ids..

```
async function test(inputs) {
    const docIds = await upload(inputs, {});
    return { ids: docIds };
}

function upload(inputs, settings) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const ids = [];
        inputs.filesToUpload.upload(settings, async (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject({ 'invalid': 'The provided data is invalid.' });
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
                let newDocument = await Document.create({ name: file.filename }).fetch();
                ids.push(newDocument.id);
            }
            resolve(ids);
        });
    });
}
```

Please note that the above function is just clarifying the use of promises.

It can be implemented in various ways specifically if we want to optimise it.

> EDIT

As an example, Promise.all can be used to optimise the upload if order is not a concern, something like like this -

```
function upload(inputs, settings) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const ids = [];
        inputs.filesToUpload.upload(settings, async (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject({ 'invalid': 'The provided data is invalid.' });
            }
            const newDocuments = await Promise.all(files.map(file => 
                Document.create({ name: file.filename }).fetch())
            );
            resolve(newDocuments.map(newDocument => newDocument.id));
        });
    });
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just don't forget to return reject method. You don't want to continue after you got error.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks @hlozancic for the correction. I should ideally use `try-catch` to make sure I'm catching uncaught exceptions, specifically from await calls. I just concentrated on the main problem and ended up writing a pseudo code which definitely has got a lot of room for improvements. I have corrected the code as per your suggestion anyway, thanks :)